# asp.net TextBox predictive text

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a list of items which is a bit too large for a dropdownlist and I'd like to add a search textbox which based on the input will drop down a list of matching items.

So if you put in John the list below would display any items that start with John.

How to go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature you are referring to is commonly labeled "AutoComplete".

If you are not at all familiar with how to do this, I would suggest following a tutorial or leveraging a pre-existing solution.

There is an example using the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit available at: 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

The basic idea is that when input is changed, JavaScript will send an asynchronous HTTP request to the server and find out what the auto-complete items should be, then it will fill the drop down options with the returned values.

Comment: ASP.NETs autocomplete works great.  I also really like JQuery's autocomplete, and with the ClientIDMode in ASP.Net webforms, Jquery is a lot easier to use than it used to be. (if the project is in MVC, JQuery is the more natural choice since all the libraries come automatically.)

Comment: I have installed the ajaxtoolkit and followed that sample but it seems things have changed since the sample was made. Having some trouble formulating the <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender> expression where its looking for a ScriptPath, something which is undefined in the sample. Is there a more descriptive sample somewhere? Also how to formulate the ServicePath, my data is coming from SP in a DB

Answer (score 0):

Well what you want to look at is the autocomplete libraries that are available. 
In your case, ASP.NET AJAX control toolkit has this functionality.

- http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

There are other options such as :

- http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx. This is from telerik and not free though.
- http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ - quite new and looks promising, but not ASP.NET specific.